# How can I add a user editable checkbox in QTableView using only QStandardItemModel

Tags: qt

I have a `QTableView` and a `QStandardItemModel`.  Is there have a column can contain checkboxes that are user editable without using delegates or using the abstract model classes? It is not that I can't do it, I just want to minimize the code, I would find it overkill for simple check boxes.

By using  `model.setData(index, Qt::Unchecked,Qt::CheckStateRole)` this creates the checkbox but it is not user editable (text beside checkbox is).

I used `modelTX.setData(index, FALSE)` but this creates a combo box containing True and False.

I'll try `setItemData`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

pls, check if the following example would work for you:

```
QStandardItemModel* tableModel = new QStandardItemModel();
// create text item
tableModel->setItem(0, 0, new QStandardItem("text item"));
// create check box item
QStandardItem* item0 = new QStandardItem(true);
item0->setCheckable(true);
item0->setCheckState(Qt::Checked);
item0->setText("some text");
tableModel->setItem(0, 1, item0);
// set model
ui->tableView->setModel(tableModel);
```

hope this helps, regards

Comment: thx for the reply.  I will tr it on monday when i come back to work but I think it will work.

Comment: it works, thanks. But how to check each checkbox if it is checked or not ?

Comment: @Suda.nese Use `item0->checkState()` fot this purpose. PS. When using Qt usually for each setter method a la `setSomething()` there is a getter named `something()`.

Comment: Your code works, but I would like to have just the checkbox without the text beside it. I didn't use `setText()` in order to avoid the text I don't want, but the column where the checkbox is, seems to be splited in two. Is there a way to avoid that?. Thanks

Comment: i know its a old thread, but i am also looking a checkbox without text around it.did you find a solution.